# Check activity of thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am running 15 threads, where the thread definitions are through a class:

```
#gpioA etc are mapped to a output port
Path = collections.OrderedDict(
(0,gpioA),(1,gpioB),
(2,gpioC),(3,gpioD),
(4,gpioE),(5,gpioF),
(6,gpioG),(7,gpioH),
(8,gpioI),(9,gpioJ),
(10,gpioK),(11,gpioL),
(12,gpioM),(13,gpioN),
(14,gpioO),(15,gpioP),))

sometime = 0.5
class myThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, id, timegap):
        self.timer = threading.Event()
        self.id = id
        self.timegap = timegap
        self.path = int(Path[id])

    def run(self):
        exit = False
        while not exit:
           self.timer.clear()
           somerandomtime = random.expovariate(1.0/self.timegap)
           exit = self.timer.wait(timeout = somerandomtime)

           if not exit:
            #change the state of a gpio pin (self.path) to low
            exit = self.timer.wait(sometime)
            #change the state of a gpio pin (self.path) to high
    def leave(self):
        self.timer.set()
```

Within each thread, I change the state of a general purpose line for 'sometime', and then give a gap of 'somerandomtime'.
The main part of the program, simply in a for loop for the elements in Path, instantiates the class, appends, and starts the threads.

I would like to know how I can check on other threads from within a thread.
for instance, `for thread n (provided n > 1 and n < 15)`, I want to check if thread `(n-1)` and `(n+1)` are NOT doing the following part of the code:

```
#change the state of a gpio pin to high
exit = self.timer.wait(sometime)
#change the state of a gpio pin to low
```

If they are running, then thread n skips this part of the code.
One way I can think of is, lock down the change of state for the gpio pin, treat it as a resource, so that it is unavailable ONLY for threads (n-1) and (n+1). The question is, can this be achieved?
Is there a different approach that can be adapted?

Comment: Other than the `is_alive` method to check on threads, I can't tell you much without seeing what you tried.

Comment: And how would you deal with the situation where you call this unidentified function, it detected that thread X was running, but by the time it returned to your code, that thread is no longer running? Or the converse, where your undesired thread wasn't running, but now it is? This sounds like an extremely fragile design that needs some re-thinking...

Comment: This is usually done with synchronization objects such as `threading.Lock`.

Comment: Try rewording or changing your question to explain the problem you are trying to solve, and not your particular solution - it would seem to most of us that what you are trying to do does not make sense, probably because you don't yet understand the right way to do what you want to do.

Comment: all, I have edited the question